Reading partial content with ASP.NET Core
My goal is to efficiently read the input form data with in my ASP.NET API controller. The concept is that the API user provides a Content-Range header and a form data and the API reads only the chunk of data specified in that header.
Since the request body is non-seekable stream - can be read only once, I cannot just use Stream.Seek method.
Here is what I tried so far:
private const ushort DefaultBufferSize = 4096;

private protected async Task<IActionResult> ReadRangedContentAsync(Func<byte[], Task<Result>> readCallback)
{
    if (!Request.HasFormContentType ||
        !MediaTypeHeaderValue.TryParse(Request.ContentType, out var contentType) ||
        !contentType.Boundary.HasValue ||
        !Request.Headers.TryGetValue(HeaderNames.ContentRange, out var contentRangeValues) ||
        !ContentRangeHeaderValue.TryParse(contentRangeValues.First(), out var contentRange) ||
        !contentRange.HasRange)
    {
        return new Result(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
    }

    var offset = contentRange.From.Value;
    var length = contentRange.To.Value - offset + 1;

    var reader = new MultipartReader(contentType.Boundary.Value, Request.Body);

    var section = await reader.ReadNextSectionAsync();

    if (section is null)
        return new Result(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);

    var buffer = new byte[length];

    await SkipBytesAsync(section.Body, offset);

    await ReadBytesAsync(section.Body, buffer);

    return await readCallback(buffer);
}

private static async Task SkipBytesAsync(Stream stream, long bytesToSkip)
{
    var trashBin = new byte[DefaultBufferSize];

    while (bytesToSkip != 0)
    {
        // TODO: Add number overflow check.
        var count = (int)Math.Min(trashBin.LongLength, bytesToSkip);

        bytesToSkip -= await stream.ReadAsync(trashBin, 0, count);
    }
}

private static async Task ReadBytesAsync(Stream stream, byte[] buffer)
{
    int bytesRead;
    var totalBytesRead = 0;

    while (totalBytesRead < buffer.Length)
    {
        var length = Math.Min(DefaultBufferSize, buffer.Length - totalBytesRead);
        var memory = buffer.AsMemory(totalBytesRead, length);

        bytesRead = await stream.ReadAsync(memory);

        if (bytesRead is 0)
            break;

        totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
    }
}

My question is - is there a better way to read the non-seekable stream? For example, I am using 4Kb array which is being overwritten over and over to "drain" stream until I reach the position described in the header, and I am curious if there a better solution in terms of memory allocations etc.

Try to use BufferedStream and here is the sample code for you.
